# search all strings with 0 0 0 0

Tags: regex, bash, grep, sh

I have output

```
Gi2/21              0          0          0          0    833603        0 
Gi5/1               0          0          0         53         0     5538
Gi6/1               0          0          2          2         0        0 
Gi6/2               0          0          0          0         0        0
```

or

```
Gi3/1               0          0          0          0
Gi2/2               0          0          0          0
```

What regex can filter all string with 0 0 0 0 0 0 or 0 0 0 0 ?

Comment: Filter in or filter out?

Comment: Try `    grep -v [1-9] output.txt  `

Comment: I would like to run something   cat log-file | grep -v '....'

Comment: Please include a sample of your desired output, what system you're on, what you've tried, and any resulting error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find lines that have multiple consecutive zeroes separated by whitespace, you can use `grep` with the following regex under the Perl regex option `-P`.

```
grep -P '0\s+0\s+0\s+0' Input.txt
```

To reverse the match, and filter out lines of this nature, just use `grep -v`.

```
grep -P -v '0\s+0\s+0\s+0' Input.txt
```

---

Without the Perl regex flag, you need to escape the `+`.

```
grep '0\s\+0\s\+0\s\+0' Input.txt
```

Comment: @uatousa, What version of grep are you running and what platform are you running on?

Comment: @uatousa, I also added a flag that might help. See the edited answer.

Comment: Actually `+` is an ExtGlob pattern, you could just use `-E`, no need for PCRE

Answer (score 0):

Given your input example, you can use `awk`.

If you *want* non zero lines:

```
awk '{sum=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i} if (sum){ print $0}}' file
```

If you *don't want* non zero lines:

```
awk '{sum=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i} if (sum==0){ print $0}}' file
```

That will work for any number of numeric fields after the first.

You can also use `sed` in this manner.

If you want the 0 only fields:

```
sed -n -E '/^[[:alnum:]\/]+[0[:blank:]]+$/p' file
```

If you want the non zero fields only, negate that match:

```
sed -n -E '/^[[:alnum:]\/]+[0[:blank:]]+$/!p' file
```

Which also works for `grep`:

```
grep -E '^[[:alnum:]\/]+[0[:blank:]]+$' file
```

or:

```
grep -E -v '^[[:alnum:]\/]+[0[:blank:]]+$' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep '0\s\+0\s\+0\s\+0'` works well